# setting constants for two views with different width in storyboard xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

I want to have two view horizontally aligned in container. both view don't have equal width. may be ratio between width could be a relation but I don't know how to set that. I tried to use UIstackView but I could not add a padding space between view after stacking both view.

[image: image 1]
Landscap mode

[image: image 2]
Portrait mode

Comment: I'd stick with the `UIStackView` approach to this. You could address the different widths by setting the Aspect Ratio for views that are members of your `UIStackView` on the Pin menu.

Comment: @AdrianB in the Pin menu I can add padding for the UIStackView but no way I can add space between the two view that are inside of UIStackView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the aspect ratio for the 2 components of your `UIStackView` so they'll stay the same on different devices with different orientations.

You can set the spacing between the views under attributes inspector for the `UIStackView` (in your case, it would be a horizontal stackView & spacing would be proportional):

[image]